# How to combine two tables in SQL with no relation between each other?

Tags: sql

Given two tables: Dim People (which contains all the sales people of the company) and Items (which contains all the items that the company sells).

I would like to combine both tables as follows. Let's say that in Dim People we have 3 rows (Sherin, Alvaro, Emad) and in Items we have 4 (1, 2, 3, 4), I would need to have something like this:

```
Sherin-1
Sherin-2
Sherin-3
Sherin-4
Alvaro-1
Alvaro-2
Alvaro-3
Alvaro-4
Emad-1
Emad-2
Emad-3
Emad-4
```

How would build the query to return this result?

Thanks in advance!

Didn't even know what to do because I've never combined two tables that have no connection between each other. I expect something like above.

Comment: Do a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Tables do not need to have a "connection" in order to use them joined together in a query. (I assume that you mean a referential constraint when you say "connection", since I am not aware of any other way to "connect" tables.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try cross join here:

```
SELECT *
FROM People, Items
```

Or explicitly:

```
SELECT *
FROM People
CROSS JOIN Items
```

Comment: I'd recommend an explicit CROSS JOIN, i.e. `FROM People CROSS JOIN Items`. It's 2022 now.